# i cannot use ts-node-dev to start ts+express+node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ts-node-dev

when I run `npm run dev`, I cannot open "http://localhost:3000" in chrome.

Executing task:

```sh
> npm run dev 

node-framework-kit@1.0.0 dev /Users/xiaoqi/node-workplace/node-framework-kit  
ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/app.ts

[INFO] 16:44:02 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.4.2)
```

[image: Screen shot]

Here is my **server.ts**:

```js
import app from './app'
const PORT=3001;

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Express server listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

here is my **app.ts**:

```js
import express from 'express' 
import {json,urlencoded} from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import morgan from 'morgan'

class App{
    public app:express.Application;
    constructor(){
        this.app=express();
        this.config();
        this.app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
            res.send({message:'hello express！！！！！'})
        })
    }
    private config(){
        this.app.use(cors())
        this.app.use(json());
        this.app.use(urlencoded({extended:false}))
        this.app.use(morgan('dev'))
    }

}
export default new App().app
```

here is my **package.json**:

```js
{
  "name": "node-framework-kit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/app.ts",
    "restart": "rimraf dist && npm run build && npm start",
    "start":"node ./dist/server.js",
    "prod":"npm run build && npm run start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
  }
}
```

here is my **tsconfig.json**:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true,  
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: sorry. its my mistake i forgot change package.json

Comment: What do you mean by *I cannot open "http://localhost:3000"*? What si the error ?

Comment: i start wrong file, run app.ts cannot start an express service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its done! just change scripts in package.json
"ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/app.ts" is wrong, need to change it to "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/server.ts"

Comment: This answer isn't helpful to other people with the same problem. Please outline what the actual problem was and how it was fixed - _what_ did you change? Thank you.

Comment: "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/app.ts" is wrong, need to change it to "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/server.ts"

Comment: @taoxiaoqi you should add it to your answer (edit).

Comment: Relax! They posted an answer when they didn't have to and you're going to downvote him? ridiculous. He was just trying to use the wrong entry file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I couldn't find any answers online, I'll answer with my solution, hopefully it might possibly help someone in the future.

Run this command `npm i pg@8.2.1` and then try again `npm run dev`

The issue was caused by `pg` being deprecated.